# Bash script using COMM and SORT issues syntax error near unexpected token

Tags: bash, comm

Linux, CentOS - to compare 2 files I use command

```
comm --check-order -1 --output-delimiter=----- <sort(file1.txt) <sort (file3.txt) > result.txt ;
```

and it works on shell, but when I try create a bash file - I have

```
syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

The script is simplest

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /var/www/html/compare/ ;
comm --check-order -1 --output-delimiter=----- <sort(file1.txt) <sort (file3.txt) > result.txt ;
exit ;
    sh
```

I already tried variations with escaping of round brackets like

```
sort\(file1.txt\)
```

or

```
sort'(file1.txt)'
```

but this case shell says

```
sort(file1.txt)...: No such file or directory
```

I tried with absolute path like

```
<sort\(var/www/html/compare/file1.txt\)
```

same result "No such file"

and I already tried run the script with variations like

```
sh /a/compare.sh
bash /a/compare.sh
chmod +x /a/compare.sh; ./a/compare.sh
```

Still same problem.

So I have OR "No such file..." with escaping of brackets - OR "unexpected token"in other cases.

Thanks in advance for any ideas to try, may be should be a right "mix" of syntax ?

Comment: [shellcheck to the rescue!](http://www.shellcheck.net/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After many combinations I found the solution where we need to force BASH with a little specific escaping.
This script works

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /var/www/html/compare/ ;
`bash -c "comm --check-order -1 --output-delimiter=----- <(sort file1.txt) <(sort file2.txt) > result.txt" ` ;
exit ;
    sh
```

Hopefully will help somebody to save the time.

Comment: late , but it helped me now ..Thanks

Answer (score 0):

## !/usr/bin/env bash

to solve it, instead of label the command, label the file

Answer (score -1):

Process substitution puts the entire command in parens.

```
... <(sort ...) ...
```

Comment: I did not catch what you mean. I tried syntax like you said `...<sort(file1.txt) <sort (file3.txt) ... ` and `...<sort(file1.txt)... ...<sort (file3.txt) ...` but same result with unexpected token. Please, add more example.

Comment: That syntax isn't at all like I said.