# UNIX 'join' command throws syntax error near unexpected token `('

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I am stuck with 'join' command in UNIX.

Requirement :
Trying to compare two files with similar meta data by embedding sort inside a join command.

Execution :

The below command works smooth in command line :

```
join -v 2 <(sort file1) <(sort file2) >difference.file
```

However when we embede this inside a shell script as given below throws a syntax error:

Script Name : join.sh

Script Content:

```
#!/bin/bash
join -v 2 <(sort file1) <(sort file2) >difference.file
#EndOfScript
```

Error message :

```
./join.sh: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./join.sh: line 1: `join -v 2 <(sort file1) <(sort file2) >difference.file'
```

Similar query was posed for `comm` and `sort` commands but this doesnt help for `join`

[Bash script using COMM and SORT issues syntax error near unexpected token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36391675/bash-script-using-comm-and-sort-issues-syntax-error-near-unexpected-token)

Comment: How do you run the script?

Comment: Your shell isn't `bash`, it is running the POSIX `sh` shell in which process substitution is not available

Comment: `join` isn't raising the error; the shell is.

Comment: @chepner kindly share a solution if you are aware of

Comment: @choroba tried using./script.sh

Comment: @choroba I have tried all the forms to run my script

Answer (score 4):

You are probably running the script with

```
sh join.sh
```

This invokes the `/bin/sh` executable, that is not compatible with bash specific syntax (the process substitution in this example).

Run the script with

```
./join.sh
```

or

```
bash join.sh
```

and it should work as expected.

Comment: So you type in the bash terminal `bash join.sh`, with the exact script you posted in the question, and get the posted error message? Or are you trying to run it programmatically with a `system` call?

Comment: I am running as it is with a bash or./ is giving me the error above

Comment: Errors in bash start with `bash:`. This type of error comes from a different shell.

Answer (score 0):

I am giving you an alternate option. You can try with this:-

```
 sort file1 > file1.dat
 sort file2 > file2.dat
 join -v 2 file1.dat file2.dat > difference.file 
 rm -rf file1.dat file2.dat
```

Comment: OP already has a shebang in his script. Bash supports process substitution.

Comment: @Aserre, I have modified my answer.

Comment: I have tried it earlier itself join inside a script irrespective of combination of commands used is giving me an error